# If $\frac{p}{q}$ has continuous fraction expansion $[a_1,...a_n]$ then $[1,a_1-1,....a_n]=\frac{p}{p-q}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $\frac{p}{q}$ has continuous fraction expansion $[a_1,...a_n]$ then $[1,a_1-1,....a_n]=\frac{p}{p-q}$

I was trying to prove this but couldn't figure it out... The text i'm reading makes it sound like it's very obvious so I suspect it should be simple to prove. Can somebody show me how to prove this? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $$a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\cdots }}=\frac{p}{q},$$ hence
$$(a_1-1)+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\cdots }}=\frac{p}{q}-1$$
and
$$1+\frac{1}{(a_1-1)+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\cdots }}}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{p}{q}-1}=\frac{p-q}{p-q}+\frac{q}{p-q}=\frac{p}{p-q}$$